Clarification needed on the notations for $g_i$-s and $f_{ji}(g_j)$ in the definition for the inverse limit for the inverse system of groups.
Background:
The following is taken from: A Graduate Course In Algebra - Volume 1
by: Ioannis Farmakis and Martin Moskowitz
Definition 1: Let $(G_i)_{i\in I}$ be a family of groups.  Then , the Cartesian product
$$\prod_{i\in I}G_i=\{f:I\to \cup_{i\in I}G_i:i\mapsto f(i)\in G_i\}$$
becomes a group under the following pointwise operation
$$f\cdot g \text{ such that }(f\cdot g)(i)=f(i)\cdot g(i)\in G_i$$
with unit element $1$ defined by $1(i)=1_{G_i}$ for each $i\in I$.
Definition 2:  Let $(I, \preceq)$ be a partially ordered set with the property that for any two elements $i,j$ there is some $k\in I$ such that $i\preceq k, j\preceq k$.
Definition 3:  An inverse system} of groups (respectively topological groups, rings, modules, topological spaces, etc) is  a family $G_i, i\in I$, of groups, together with a fmaily of homomorphisms $f_{ij}:G_i\to G_j,i\succeq j$ such that :

$f_{ii}=1_{G_i}.$

Whenever $i\succeq j \succeq k,$ then $f_{ik}=f_{jk}\circ f_{ij}.$


Definition 4:  The inverse (or projective limit of the inverse system of groups $G_i,$ is defined by giving a group $G$ and a homomorphism $$\phi_i:G\to G_i$$
for each $i\in I$ satisfying

If $i \succeq j$ then $\phi_j= f_{ij}\circ \phi_i$, i.e. the homomorphism $\phi_i$ are compatible with the inverse system.

Given another group $H$ and $\psi_i:G_i\to H$ compatible with the inverse system, then there is a unique homomorphism $\psi:H\to G$ such that $\psi_i=\phi_i\circ \psi$ for any $i \in I$.
We write


$$G=\varprojlim_{i\in I}G_i$$.
In the categories of sets, groups, rings etc., inverse limits alwaysexist and admit the following description:
$$\varprojlim_{i\in I}G_i=\{(g_i)\in \prod_{i\in I}G_i\mid f_{ji}(g_j)=g_i \text{ for all }i\preceq j\}$$.
Questions:
In continuation from this post. I have some questions about clarifications need for the  notations $g_i$-s,$f_{ji}(g_j)$ for Definition 4 above,
In $2.$ for Definition 4, concerning the set $\{(g_i)\in \prod_{i\in I}G_i\mid f_{ji}(g_j)=g_i \text{ for all }i\preceq j\}$, specifically the elements $g_i$s of $(g_i)\in \prod_{i\in I}G_i$ and $f_{ji}(g_j)$; is each $g_i$ a map defined as $g_i:I\to \cup_{i\in I}G_i:=i\mapsto g(i)\in G_i$ according to Definition 1 above and moreover, each $f_{ji}(g_j)$ is a composition map defined as $I\xrightarrow{g_j}\cup_{j\in I}G_j\xrightarrow{f_{ji}}G_i=I\xrightarrow{g_{i}}G_i$.
Thank you in advance

It is really helpful to think less pedantically set-theoretically and just talk of "families of elements" $g_i\in G_i$, then $f_{ji}(g_j)$ just literally is the evaluation of $f_{ji}$ at the element $g_j$. That's the kind of thing this notation is good for. The definition via choice functions $I\to\bigcup_i G_i$ is correct and we need it for foundational reasons but don't get too hung up on it, in my opinion.
But if we must, $g_i$ is not a function $I\to\bigcup_i G_i$. Rather an element of the product $\prod_i G_i$ is a choice function $g:I\to\bigcup_i G_i$, and "$g_i$" would be the evaluation $g(i)$. The condition $f_{ji}(g_j)=g_i$ is defined elementwise for a reason. The composition $f_{ji}\circ g:I\to\bigcup_i G_i\to\bigcup_i G_i$ does not make any sense, I'm sorry to say, because $f_{ji}:G_j\to G_i$ is not defined on the union.
However in keeping with the general construction of limits, we could describe the "$f_{ji}(g_j)=g_i$" condition more abstractly via consideration of the two maps: $$\alpha:\prod_j G_j\longrightarrow\prod_{i\preceq j}G_i,\,\pi_{i\preceq j}\alpha=f_{ji}\pi_j\\\beta:\prod_j G_j\longrightarrow\prod_{i\preceq j}G_i,\,\pi_{i\preceq j}\beta=\pi_i$$
And then we could say $\varprojlim G_i$ is the subset of $\prod_j G_j$ consisting of those $g$ ($g:I\to\bigcup_i G_i$ a choice function) such that $\alpha(g)=\beta(g)$ (the equaliser). This method makes no reference to specific elements.

Thank you for your clear answers as always.  How have you been?  Are you in grad school doing category theory and algebraic topology?  Are things going well with you in general and also with school. Can I trouble you with the following few posts: post 1, for correct set builder notation for the set of  equivalence classes and quotient set $\varinjlim_{i\in I}G_i=\oplus_i G_i$...

...post 2, on correct notation for the equivalence relation $\sim$ defined in the quotient set $\varinjlim_{i\in I}G_i=\oplus_i G_i$ and also about this post 3. about how to define a compatible function $f$  They are all about notations.

@Seth Hi! Yes all is well with me and school. Hopefully likewise for you.
